# Performance using Span<T> to parse a text file

Tags: c#

I am trying to take advantage of `Span<T>`, using **.NETCore 2.2** to improve the performance of parsing text from a text file. The text file contains multiple consecutive rows of data which will each be split into fields that are then each mapped to a data class.

Initially, the parsing routine uses a traditional approach of using `StreamReader` to read each row, and then using `Substring` to copy the individual fields from that row.

From what I have read ([on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx)), amongst others, using `Span<T>` with `Slice` should perform more efficiently as less data allocations are made, and instead, a pointer to the `byte[]` array is passed around and acted upon.

After some experimentation I have compared 3 approaches to parsing the file and used BenchmarkDotNet to compare the results. What I found was that, when parsing a single row from the text file using `Span`, both mean execution time and allocated memory are indeed significantly less. So far so good. However, when parsing more than one row from the file, the performance gain quickly disappears to the point that it is almost insignificant, even from as little as 50 rows.

[image: benchmark results]

I am sure I must be missing something. Something seems to be outweighing the performance gain of `Span`.

The best performing approach `WithSpan_StringFirst` looks like this:

```
private static byte[] _filecontent;
private const int ROWSIZE = 252;
private readonly Encoding _encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

public void WithSpan_StringFirst()
{
    var buffer1 = new Span<byte>(_filecontent).Slice(0, RowCount * ROWSIZE);
    var buffer = _encoding.GetString(buffer1).AsSpan();

    int cursor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
        var row = buffer.Slice(cursor, ROWSIZE);
        cursor += ROWSIZE;
        Foo.ReadWithSpan(row);
    }
}

[Params(1, 50)]
public int RowCount { get; set; }
```

Implementation of `Foo.ReadWithSpan`:

```
public static Foo ReadWithSpan(ReadOnlySpan<char> buffer) => new Foo
{
    Field1 = buffer.Read(0, 2),
    Field2 = buffer.Read(3, 4),
    Field3 = buffer.Read(5, 6),
    // ...
    Field30 = buffer.Read(246, 249)
};

public static string Read(this ReadOnlySpan<char> input, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    return new string(input.Slice(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
}
```

Any feedback would be appreciated. I have posted a [full working sample](https://github.com/Chris197/FileParseWithSpanBenchmark) on github.

Comment: what runtime are you testing on here? this **really** matters? .NET Framework, .NET Core "current" and .NET Core "legacy" have very different spans - functionally equivalent, but completely different internals

Comment: Using dotnet core 2.2, I'll update the description, thanks.

Comment: @PeterB it exists down to .NET 4.5 and .NET Standard 1.0, IIRC - see System.Memory on nuget (edit: my bad, it was .NET Standard 1.1)

Comment: I am targeting .NET Core 2.2, not Framework or Standard.

Comment: @PeterB ah, I see what you're getting at, but: it is the "Foundational-APIs working with spans" that are limited; that just means you need to `#if` and `unsafe` in a few places

Comment: Span is only going to reduce allocations depending on what you do with the spans. In this case, you immediately create new strings from them, which is exactly what `Substring` does, so you are gaining very little. If you were processing the substring (e.g. parsing to `double`) instead, you would gain an advantage from `Span`.

Comment: You're doing too much unneeded work. Read file by ROWSIZE portions into some arr[chars]. Next use standard "new string(char[] value, int startIdx, int length)" constructor  to create values from each column.

Answer (score -3):

For small files < 10,000 lines and simple line structure to parse, most any .net Core method will be the same.

For large, multi-gigibyte files and millions of lines of data, optimizations matter more.

If file processing time is in hours or even in tens of minutes, getting all the C# code together in the same class will drastically speed up processing the file as the compiler can do better code optimizations.   Inlining the methods called into the main processing code can help also.

**It's the same 1960s answer, changing the processing algorithm and how it chunks input and output data is an order of magnitude better than small code optimizations.**